# How to prevent HTML checkboxes or radio buttons from shrinking in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, layout, checkbox, label

See screenshots:

[image: Shrunk radio button]
[image: Shrunk checkboxes]

Is there a simple way to prevent some of the checkboxes from being squashed in Chrome? (They are all the same size in Firefox).

Here's an example HTML fragment for a checkbox/label pair:

```
<span class="form-col">
    <input type="checkbox" value="-Min accompanied adults" id="product-type-checkbox9">
    <label for="product-type-checkbox9">-Min accompanied adults</label>
</span>
```

Comment: We'll need to see the relevant CSS. But my guess is that somewhere, the checkbox and the label are getting mixed up.

Comment: I'm Facing same issue @Steve is this fixed.. ?

Comment: Sorry @Vivek but this was over a year and a half ago and I'm working on a different project now. Guess a bounding div around the whole fragment might somewhat help - at least they'd then all shrink consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span>
    <br>input type="checkbox" style="min-width:13px!important" value="-Min accompanied adults" id="product-type-checkbox9"
<br>
    label for="product-type-checkbox9"-Min accompanied adults/label
<br>
</span>
```

Just setting up the minimum width of the checkbox will do the needful.
Here I have written inline style(just for example) which should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: +1 Nearly two years later I've just had a similar issue but with radio buttons rather than checkboxes and this solution fixed it - interestingly 13px is also just the right size for radio buttons - any less and it starts to shrink.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="squaredTwo">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredTwo" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredTwo"></label>
    </div>`


    ` /* SQUARED TWO */
    .squaredTwo {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
    }

    .squaredTwo label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit- box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
    }

    .squaredTwo label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .squaredTwo label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
    }

    .squaredTwo input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    }`
```

Comment: What do you mean, cHao??  must I use his exact coding? let him try the coding and see what happens... He can put in his own words...

Comment: I mean that the question has absolutely nothing to do with backgrounds (let alone gradients), positioning, alpha filters, rotation, etc etc etc, and adding them just makes stuff confusing.  Just like we expect a question to contain a *short but self-contained* code sample to illustrate the problem, so too do we expect an answer not to contain so much extra crap that the answer gets lost in the noise.

Comment: Yes, it is. It has nothing to do with the question. Not to mention, the code would not even work -- you are using class selectors in your css but you have used an ID on the checkbox.